# Arduino trim: does it remove the \n as well?

Tags: serial

According to the manual:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringTrim

Trim strips one or more whitespaces from the beginning and the end. Does it also removes tabulators and \n ?

I have the following code which works:

```
 while (Serial.available()) {   // something came across the serial   
      char c = (char)Serial.read();
      Command += c;
      Command.trim();
      if (c=='\n')
         {
           Complete =true;
         }   
   if (Command.length() >0 && Complete) {

        if (Command == "LED_ON") {
               // Do stuff
        }
```

Although I'm not sure that it is working because of the last if statement which says: if (Command == "LED_ON") ignores the ending \n and say ok it matched OR Command.trim() really takes off that \n.

Thank you

Comment: OMG, he's using String! Argh! That's evil! I suggest you learn how to do things properly and don't rely on (broken) crutches like String. https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/ https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/

Comment: I would make a general comment saying that similar functions in other programming languages that do 'trim' remove all whitespace which usually includes newlines spaces tabs carriage return etc etc. Its been confirmed that this version of trim does that but newlines and tab are generally considered whitespace in most languages.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, \n is also removed.

The source for the trim() function is in [WString.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/be9bbc3255e784108fc10a069d79a4fa8b4ca37e/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.cpp#L719-L729).

```
void String::trim(void)
{
    if (!buffer || len == 0) return;
    char *begin = buffer;
    while (isspace(*begin)) begin++;
    char *end = buffer + len - 1;
    while (isspace(*end) && end >= begin) end--;
    len = end + 1 - begin;
    if (begin > buffer) memcpy(buffer, begin, len);
    buffer[len] = 0;
}
```

We can see it uses the `isspace()` function, but where's that function defined? `WString.cpp` only `#include`s `WString.h`, so we go there.

In `WString.h`, we can see [it includes `ctype.h`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/WString.h#L28). Time to go to the [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isspace/), which tells us that yes, `\n` is a "space" according to isspace(), so it is trimmed.

(note that `isspace()` is affected by localization settings. I'm not sure what the localization settings are when compiling for Arduino)

Answer (score 1):

Whilst rchard2scout is quite right that `trim` will remove newlines, why not rearrange the code so it doesn't matter?

```c++
  char c = (char)Serial.read();
  if (c == '\n')
     Complete = true;
  else
     Command += c;
```